# Defined Component is not accessible in App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component with Home is not accessible in my App.js component.
Home.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import "./Home.scss



const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="home">Home</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

This is my App.js Code

```
import "./pages/home/Home"


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Home/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am facing the error:

```
[eslint] 
src/App.js
  Line 8:6:  'Home' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
ERROR in [eslint] 
src/App.js
  Line 8:6:  'Home' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I am expecting to access Home component in App.js file

Comment: Change the import statement `import "./pages/home/Home"`  **to** `import Home from './pages/home/Home'`

Comment: Try `import Home from "./pages/home/Home"`

Comment: try  "./pages/home/Home"

Answer (score 2):

Add reference when you file import like this

```
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
```

Answer (score 0):

In App.js your import should be

```
import Home from "./pages/home/Home"
```

Then you can use it

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import Home from "./pages/home/Home"
```

if next time you are not using export default, you need to do destructuring

```
import {moduleA, moduleB} from "./pages/home/Home"

assume you are exporting moduleA and moduleB without export default keyword
```